# Test set distribution different than train set distribution

Tags: regression, distributions

I am doing regression to predict a target. My model is giving low mse on the training data but very high mse on the testing data( even worse than baseline predict all as mean model). I thought this would be because of overfitting, so i fitted a fine tuned elastic net model on the same,but the same problem still persists. Then i saw the distributions for my test and train targets and saw it is completely different! What should i do in this case?
[image]

[image]

EDIT : Actually it makes sense that the distribution is way different because of the nature of the target i'm prediction. Basically what is target is "Number of days since default". That is `date when he took loan - first instance when he didn't pay his EMI`  My test set is single month data that is of June'16. And my training set is everything since Dec'15 to Feb'17 except Jun'16 ones. So basically the people who took loans in Dec'15 will have more number of days. What should i do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is called [**covariate shift adaption**](http://sifaka.cs.uiuc.edu/jiang4/domain_adaptation/survey/node8.html). The difference between training data and testing data will lead to failure prediction.

A formal definition is given as follows: $P_{train}(Y|X)=P_{test}(Y|X)$, but $P_{train}(X)\neq P_{test}(X)$, which is defnitely problem you state above. One example is shown below:
[image]

This problem can be well solved by incorporating the ratio $\frac{P_{test}(X)}{P_{train}(X)}$ into the loss function. So your loss function should be defined as 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{P_{test}(X)}{P_{train}(X)} loss(x_i, y_i)
$$

The estimate of density ratio $\frac{P_{test}(X)}{P_{train}(X)}$ is well studied in [Sugiyama's Group](http://www.ms.k.u-tokyo.ac.jp/publications.html), and you may find proper method and code on his website for your experiment.